# Argument about what is infinity mathematically

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

My brother argues that "infinity is a quantity,an infinite number". I argued back saying infinity is a concept, a quality rather than an actual quantity. My brother was saying that $\frac{5}{\infty} \to 0$, but I argued that infinity on its own cannot be placed in a math expression in this manner, rather it is usually a part of an operator like a limit because $x \to \infty$ means $x$ increases and increases continuously forever not to an "infinite quantity. Who is right?

Can infinity, under any circumstance, be considered a quantity, or is infinity just a property, a concept?

Edit: The possible duplicate does not answer the question as to whether infinity can be called a quantity, mathematically.

Comment: It depends on the context. In high school mathematics infinity is to be taken as a specific notational expression while in topology infinity is considered as a point in the extended real number system, that is, an (infinite) number.

Comment: There are many concepts with the name “infinity”. In some of them, infinity is a quantity, in others it’s a number. And still in others, it’s just a notational shorthand … My take on your specific question: In most precalculus scenarios, it’s treated as a number even though it isn’t given any justification and should really be thought of as a mere shorthand.

Comment: I am voting to close as a duplicate, but I suggest you take another look at the linked question to see *mathematical* answers to your question. 

The first sentence of two of the answers is clear: "Infinity is not a real number". 

You might well be unsatisfied with that sentence regarding "the question as to whether infinitely can be called a quantity, mathematically". But the trouble is that "quantity" is more a philosophical concept that a mathematical concept, *outside of the choice of the real numbers (and, sometimes, other kinds of numbers) as mathematical models of "quantity"*.

Comment: I agree, I took a look into all the other related threads and I am satisfied, please close this thread if possible.

Comment: @Bandoo: I'm glad to hear that you're satisfied with the related threads, but I would like to make things as clear as possible for you. Like all concepts in mathematics, "∞" must be defined in a meaningful way before we can talk about it. Due to lack of available symbols, people use the same symbol "∞" to mean different concepts in different (mathematical) contexts, such as the affinely-extended real line, the real projective line, the complex projective plane, the infinity in measure theory, ... But the bottom-line is that it is all about **precise** definitions and what we can prove.

Comment: And sometimes "∞" is nothing more than a syntactic part of a notation, such as in "$\sum_{k=1}^∞$", and **not** an object in itself. And in case people tell you that "∞/∞" is an indefinite form, that's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the context whether your approach is the right one (it often is), but I don't think your brother is presenting you with the right alternative (there are many in fact, it's really context dependent).

For example, in measure theory, when your goal is to measure "lengths" of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, it makes sense to assign $+\infty$ to things like $(a,+\infty)$ or $(-\infty,\infty)$, for example. Here you'd treat $+\infty$ as a specific quantity, a specific "length", rather than just a "limit".

Another case would be when you take the one-point compactification of the complex plane, for example. Roughly speaking, this means that you can look at the sphere $S^2$ as the complex plane, with one pole being the origin, and the opposite pole being infinity.